# Yii2 pjax call results in unserialize error

Tags: yii2, pjax

I have a customer view page where I can show their unpaid invoices by month. By default it will show the current month but there will be links to the past month and next month.

I want to use PJAX call to update unpaid invoices list by selected month, but it gave me unserialize error. Can someone help me on how to implement PJAX on this case?

Below is my controller code

public function actionView($id, $unpaidPeriod = null) {
$request = Yii::$app->request;

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);

$unpaidPeriod = empty($unpaidPeriod) ? date('Y-m-d') : $unpaidPeriod;
$unpaidPeriodBef = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($unpaidPeriod . '-1 month'));
$unpaidPeriodAft = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($unpaidPeriod . '+1 month'));

return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
        'unpaidPeriod' => $unpaidPeriod, 'unpaidPeriodBef' => $unpaidPeriodBef, 'unpaidPeriodAft' => $unpaidPeriodAft,
        ]);
```

}

and below is the view code

...
[customer detail view]
....

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'unpaid-invoice-pjax']) ?>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px; display: flex; align-items: baseline;">
    <span class="col-md-2 text-left">
        <?= Html::a(Html::icon('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left') . ' ' . Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($unpaidPeriodBef, 'php: F Y'), Url::to(['view', 'id' => $model->id, 'unpaidPeriod' => $unpaidPeriodBef]), ['data-pjax' => '#unpaid-invoice-pjax', 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-info']) ?>
    </span>
    <span class="col-md-8 text-center">
        <legend><?= Yii::t('app', 'Unpaid invoice list') . ' ' . Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($unpaidPeriod, 'php: F Y') ?></legend>
    </span>
    <span class="col-md-2 text-right">
        <?php if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($unpaidPeriodAft)) <= date('Y-m-d')) { ?>
            <?= Html::a(Html::icon('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right') . ' ' . Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($unpaidPeriodAft, 'php: F Y'), Url::to(['view', 'id' => $model->id, 'unpaidPeriod' => $unpaidPeriodAft]), ['data-pjax' => '#unpaid-invoice-pjax', 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-info']) ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </span>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 150px;"><?= FormHeader::instance()->getAttributeLabel('formNo') ?></th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 200px;"><?= FormHeader::instance()->getAttributeLabel('formDate') ?></th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 150px;"><?= FormHeader::instance()->getAttributeLabel('totalCharges') ?></th>
        <th class="text-center"><?= FormHeader::instance()->getAttributeLabel('memo') ?></th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php if (empty($model->getMonthlyUnpaidInvoices($unpaidPeriod)->all())) { ?>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="5"><?= Html::tag('strong', Yii::t('app', 'No data available'), ['class' => 'text-danger bg-danger', 'style' => 'padding: 3px 8px;']) ?></th>
        </tr>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php $totInvoices = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($model->getMonthlyUnpaidInvoices($unpaidPeriod)->all() as $invoice) { ?>
            <?php $totInvoices += $invoice->totalInvoice; ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?= Html::a($invoice->formNo, Url::to(['/forms/warehouse-sales/view', 'id' => $invoice->id])) ?></td>
                <td class="text-center"><?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($invoice->formDate) ?></td>
                <td class="text-right"><?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($invoice->totalInvoice) ?></td>
                <td><?= $invoice->memo ?></td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <?=
                    Html::a(
                            Html::icon('glyphicon glyphicon-usd') . ' ' . Yii::t('app', 'Pay'), Url::to(['/forms/warehouse-sales/pay', 'id' => $invoice->id, 'custview' => 1]), [
                        'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-success',
                        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Pay'),
                        'data-pjax' => 0,
                        'data-method' => 'post',
                        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('app', 'Are you sure you want to set the status to Paid?'),
                            ]
                    )
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" colspan="2"><?= Yii::t('app', 'TOTAL') ?></th>
            <th class="text-right"><?= Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($totInvoices) ?></th>
            <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

....
Below is the error message from yii debug

unserialize('O:31:"yii\base\UnknownMethodException":7:{s:10:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'message";s:0:"";s:17:"' . "\0" . 'Exception' . "\0" . 'string";s:0:"";s:7:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'code";i:0;s:7:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'file";s:81:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure.php";s:7:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'line";i:415;s:16:"' . "\0" . 'Exception' . "\0" . 'trace";a:10:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:81:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure.php";s:4:"line";i:415;s:8:"function";s:29:"newInstanceWithoutConstructor";s:5:"class";s:15:"ReflectionClass";s:4:"type";s:2:"->";}i:1;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:81:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure.php";s:4:"line";i:390;s:8:"function";s:12:"wrapClosures";s:5:"class";s:32:"Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure";s:4:"type";s:2:"::";}i:2;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:81:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure.php";s:4:"line";i:390;s:8:"function";s:12:"wrapClosures";s:5:"class";s:32:"Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure";s:4:"type";s:2:"::";}i:3;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:81:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure.php";s:4:"line";i:390;s:8:"function";s:12:"wrapClosures";s:5:"class";s:32:"Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure";s:4:"type";s:2:"::";}i:4;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:67:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/opis/closure/functions.php";s:4:"line";i:19;s:8:"function";s:12:"wrapClosures";s:5:"class";s:32:"Opis\Closure\SerializableClosure";s:4:"type";s:2:"::";}i:5;a:3:{s:4:"file";s:77:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/src/LogTarget.php";s:4:"line";i:62;s:8:"function";s:22:"Opis\Closure\serialize";}i:6;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:77:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/src/LogTarget.php";s:4:"line";i:136;s:8:"function";s:6:"export";s:5:"class";s:19:"yii\debug\LogTarget";s:4:"type";s:2:"->";}i:7;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:72:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Dispatcher.php";s:4:"line";i:189;s:8:"function";s:7:"collect";s:5:"class";s:19:"yii\debug\LogTarget";s:4:"type";s:2:"->";}i:8;a:5:{s:4:"file";s:68:"/home/dadinugroho/projects/xinsys/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Logger.php";s:4:"line";i:177;s:8:"function";s:8:"dispatch";s:5:"class";s:18:"yii\log\Dispatcher";s:4:"type";s:2:"->";}i:9;a:3:{s:8:"function";s:5:"flush";s:5:"class";s:14:"yii\log\Logger";s:4:"type";s:2:"->";}}s:19:"' . "\0" . 'Exception' . "\0" . 'previous";N;}')

TIA

Daniel

Comment: where is your <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy. Pjax begin is right on top of div class row

Comment: This error is in your first page load or only after pjax? Do you use this vendor extention `opis/closure/src/SerializableClosure` here? Where?

Comment: I used standard yii2. I dont know what is the opis/closure?

Comment: This extension seems to be installed, can you run a `composer depends opis/closure`? This library isn't installed by Yii2 default templates.

Comment: when run composer depends opis/closure,  it shows 

yiisoft/yii2-debug  2.0.x-dev  requires  opis/closure (^3.3)

Comment: Try updating the `opis/closure` to version 3.6.1. They fixed a `SeriaziableClousure` error, just as the one you are getting.

Comment: Try it without pjax if it will works than perfect than it is pjax error else another error

Comment: it runs but showing pjax error. I think if pjax is error then will refresh the whole page?

Comment: I updating opis.closure but still get the same error.